# How to create nested selects with sql?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I want to select all entities that are tied by a custom hierarchy:

```
@Entity
class Employee {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Company company;
}

@Entity
class Company {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private LeisureGroup leisureGroup;
}

@Entity
class LeisureGroup {
    @Id
    private long id;
}
```

//select all companies that belong to a LeisureGroup

```
Select * from company where leisureGroupId = '123'
```

TODO: how can I select all employees that belong to the LeisureGroup (tied by the Company reference)? Do I have to use `joins` here? If yes, how?

Comment: You don't use SQL if you want to query through JPA, you use JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) or HQL (Hibernate Query Language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use SQL if you want to query through JPA, you use JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) or HQL (Hibernate Query Language) (for Hibernate users).

JPQL query (requires an `EntityManager` variable called `em`)

```
public List<Employee> findEmployeesInLeisureGroup(final Integer leisureGroupId) {
    final TypedQuery<Employee> query =
        em.createQuery("select e " +
                       "from Employee e join e.company c join c.leisureGroup l " +
                       "where l.id = :leisureGroupId", Employee.class);
    query.setParameter("leisureGroupId", leisureGroupId);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

SQL equivalent:

```
select * from Employee
where company_id in (select id from Company where leisureGroup_id = 123);
```

Comment: I'm programming directly in StackOverflow here, no guarantee it will actually work :p I can't really put my finger on why it doesn't work, but at least you have an example of joining with JPQL. Also, don't expect to run this as SQL, this is a JPA query.

Comment: Your sql will only work if the subselect returns only one row/one result. But there will mostly be more than one company assigned to the same leisuregroup...

Comment: Fixed, found that I didn't need to reference the LeisureGroup table but forgot to change the `=` to `in`..

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
Select e from Employee e where e.company.id= (select c.id from Company c where c. leisureGroup.id=:id
```

Comment: I want to select all employees`, not companies!

Comment: This works if there is only one `company` assigned to a `leisuregroup`. But for 2+ companies assigned this will return "result has more than one row". But this will mostly be the case due to the `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Is this a JPQL query or SQL query?